Gathering C++ libraries versions
I have several CMake-based static libraries written in C++. I'd like to have a C++ function get_libs_versions() that can be called in a consumer of these libs and get a string which contains all Mercurial changesets of these linked libraries. I know how to extract changesets using find_package(Hg).
Example output:
lib1_changeset=0xblablabla 

lib2_changeset=0xabc

How this can be organized? I suppose that CMake should generate source file in a build directory with get_libs_versions() implementation.

Are you looking for configure_file?

I would probably make a script which is presented with a list of all the libraries, or at least their repositories, and then gets the data you need and build a source file containing the information. The application target then uses this source file when building, and you could make any API you need to get the information.

Do you want the set of version numbers returned by get_libs_versions() to be determined at build time or at run time?

@Peter, I mean build time.
